# OSError: [WinError 123], it adds simbols to file path and raise this error

Tags: python, directory, operating-system

I am trying to open a directory:

```py
os.chdir('D:\movies\ClassicMusic\GRANDES COMPOSITORES DA MUSICA CLASSICA\17 - Verdi (Grandes Compositores da Música Clássica - Abril Coleções)')
```

but I get this error:

```py
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'D:\\movies\\ClassicMusic\\GRANDES COMPOSITORES DA MUSICA CLASSICA\x0f - Verdi (Grandes Compositores da Música Clássica - Abril Coleções)'
```

`os` changes the `17` in the name of directory to `x0f` and raises the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backslash character '' in strings introduces an "escape sequence", it tells the python parser to change its interpretation of the following character. For example, the two characters '\n' get replaced by a single 'newline' character.

This is not what you want, so you can turn off this meaning of backslash by using a **raw string**, prefixed by '**r**':

```
os.chdir(r'D:\movies\ClassicMusic\GRANDES COMPOSITORES DA MUSICA CLASSICA\17 - Verdi (Grandes Compositores da Música Clássica - Abril Coleções)'
```